# i want to use integer and float in objective-c for a same function?

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an calculator in xcode using Objective-C i used float in syntax but i want that when answer is float calculator show float type not integer only and i want that when answer is integer it show integer when answer is float it shows float.
here is code
https://github.com/syntaxxerrorr/Calculator

Comment: so the way you worded this is a bit confusing. You don't want a float when your not working with an integer correct?

Just always use a float and when you need a whole number round it.

I actually made a calculator not that long ago, so reword what your asking a little and I can just look up in my code :)

Comment: Sounds like a formatting problem.  Pick a single internal representation for all internal calculations and values.  Float is a fine choice.  Numerical results are always presented to the user as strings.  Use NSNumberFormatter for the most power in producing properly formatted strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Test whether the value is int or not. You can do it like this:

   `if (fmod(fVal, 1.0) == 0.0)
   // is integer`
2. Get integer result:

   `int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );`

Display the corresponding value, using the condition.

Comment: float convertRT;
int RunningTotalint;

convertRT = truncf(RunningTotal);
RunningTotalint = (int)convertRT;

if(RunningTotal == convertRT)
{
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", RunningTotal];
}else{
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", RunningTotal];
}

Comment: solved in line { Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", RunningTotal]
you just missed running totalint { Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", RunningTotalint] at the end

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
float answer = 12.0;
float truncAnswer;
int intAnswer;

truncAnswer = truncf(answer);
intAnswer = (int)truncAnswer;

if(answer == truncAnswer)
{
    NSLog(@"Integer Answer = %d", intAnswer);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Float Answer = %f", answer);
}
```

If you change the initialization of answer to 12.0, it will print the integer answer.

Comment: here is source code please check and help me
https://github.com/syntaxxerrorr/Calculator

Answer (score 0):

Do you know `NSNumber` in Objective-C is a class represent for Float, Double, Int, Integer, etc? So you can return NSNumber in your function.

Let's try to use it.